# Convert/Warp raster imagedata from EPSG31466 to 4326 for OpenStreepMap overlay

Tags: openstreetmap, gdal

I have a raster image in Gauss Krüger 2 projection that I need to use as overlay in OpenStreetMap and learned so far that I need to warp/translate/convert the image using tools like GDAL.

I tried gdalwarp with the following results:

```
$ gdalwarp -s_srs 'EPSG:31466' -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' kg2-map.png osm-map.tiff
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line
and georeferenced coordinates for /kg2-map.png
There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.
```

What do I need to do in order do get this task done?

Comment: The OSM slippy maps are projected using `EPSG:3857`, are you sure you dont need that? The original data of OSM is stored in `EPSG:4326` though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to georeference the PNG source file, so that each pixel has a coordinate and resolution. If you know the coordinate of the top left corner and the resolution, make a 6-line [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) named `kg2-map.pngw` or `kg2-map.pgw`.

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. I know the (almost) exact lon/lat for the north/western corner. and I know the lon/lat of the South/Western corner. How can I determine the resolution from this information?

Comment: You don't need the lat/long, you need the source coordinates, which according to [this](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31466/) is in meters, so it is an easting and northing. The resolution can be determined by looking at the projected distance of length or width in metres and dividing by the number of rows or columns.